# GPG encryption and decryption of a folder using command line

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption, gnupg

man page of gpg command line (Gnupg) has commands to encrypt and decrypt files. Here is a standard command to encrypt/decrypt files with gpg.

`gpg --encrypt --recipient xxx@mail.com ~/xxx/xxx.txt` - to encrypt

`gpg --output ~/xxx/xxx.txt --decrypt ~/xxx/xxx.gpg` - to decrypt

But if i have a folder with multiple files and folders, how can i encrypt it with command line?

Comment: Here is your answer: http://superuser.com/a/973338. Btw this question seems to be off-topic for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Use gpg-zip.

Encrypt the contents of directory mydocs for user Bob to file test1:

```
gpg-zip --encrypt --output test1 --gpg-args  -r Bob mydocs
```

List the contents of archive test1:

```
gpg-zip --list-archive test1
```

This is an example directly from [Encrypt or sign files into an archive](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/gpg_002dzip.html). If you read that page in detail it will help you out a lot.

**Solution 2:**

Turn a directory into a file

If you want to encrypt a directory, you will need to convert it to a file first. Run the command:

```
tar czf myfiles.tar.gz mydirectory/
```

This gives you a new file 'myfiles.tar.gz' which you can then encrypt/decrypt. To turn a tarball back into a directory:

```
tar xzf myfiles.tar.gz
```

now you can use encrypt in the same way that you have above. So:

```
gpg --encrypt --recipient xxx@mail.com ~/xxx/xxx.txt
```

This is taken directly from an example on [berkeley encrypting](http://statistics.berkeley.edu/computing/encrypt), which is also a quick and useful read.

You can review the man page here: [gnu gpg man](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual.html)

Comment: In line with solution 2, http://duplicity.nongnu.org/ creates an encrypted tar and provides for transferring to remote locations via various means with the space-efficient rsync protocol.

Comment: I had to put quotes around gpg-args's parameter: --gpg-args "-r Bob"

Comment: `gpg-zip` is now deprecated, and `gpgtar` is recommended.

Comment: Using tar's compressing `z` flag in the first command is usually a waste of resources since gpg already does some compression. Default is `--compress-algo zip` with a compression level of `6`.

Comment: @mxmehl `gpg`, if asked to encrypt a file that is already compressed, will detect that and disable its own compression. Hene the data will be compressed exactly once whether `tar` is used with compression enabled or not. This behaviour is specified in `gpg`s `man` pages, and `gpg` will report what it does with regards to this if invoked with with `gpg -v`.

Answer (score 17):

**gpgtar** is another option as well. gpgtar encrypts or signs files into an archive.  It is a gpg-ized tar using the same format as used by PGP's PGP Zip.

It installs along with gnupg on MacOS and Linux.

**Encrypt Directory**

```
gpgtar --encrypt --output <out_file_name> -r <recipient> <dir_name>
```

**Decrypt Directory**

```
gpgtar --decrypt <out_file_name>
```

[gpgtar man page](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/gpgtar.html)

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to tarball everything together and want to encrypt multiple files individually:

`cd` into the folder

**encrypt:** `$ls | gpg --multifile --encrypt` or  `$ls | gpg --encrypt-files -r <recipient>`

**decrypt:** `$ls | gpg --multifile --decrypt` or `$ls | gpg --decrypt-files`