# GPG - Command to Encrypt contents of folder - All files

Tags: pgp, openpgp

I'm trying to encrypt all the files in folder    **C:\TEST**
What is the command to encrypt all the files in **C:\TEST** using key  **email@gmail.com** to a new file T**EST.GPG**

`GPG.EXE --encrypt C:\TEST  email@gmail.com`              ??

thx

Comment: Well, what happens when you try that?

Comment: usage : gpg[options] --encrypt [filename]

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584461/gpg-encryption-and-decryption-of-a-folder-using-command-line). It is not Windows-specific, but I think the answers will basically work for you.

Comment: still can't get it to work with GPG